# Outputting a poem in C with each word being on a new line

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I have an assignment in a C programming class to output a poem with each word on a new line, using only the functions `getchar` and `putchar`. I have the majority of the program written, but I can't figure out how to only have one new line for multiple spaces. For example, when there is more than one space there is a gap in the output, which I don't want. Does anyone know how to correct this?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* Variables declared */
    int iochar;

    /* While loop */
    while ((iochar = getchar() ) != EOF) {

        /* If statement to return on alphabetic characters, not puncuation */
        if (((iochar >= 'A') && (iochar <= 'Z')) || ((iochar >= 'a') && (iochar <= 'z'))) {
            putchar(iochar);
        }

        /* If statement to produce a new line when a space is detected */
        if (iochar == ' ') {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AJMansfield: No, it shouldn't, because the homework tag was declared obsolete.

Comment: @Philipp What does one use for that?  Or is there even anything used now?  Thanks for saying so, I was unaware of that.

Comment: @AJMansfield There is nothing used anymore. It was decided that there should not be any special treatment of homework questions, so no tag is needed. See [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100) for more.

Comment: I'll post the final code later for anyone who might be interested in it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the previous character in another variable and only output a line break when the current character is a space AND the previous character was not a space.

By the way: what is supposed to happen with numbers in the input?

Comment: That seems like it may work. Thank you. I'll try it now and get back. I didn't account for numbers because the input we were given is just a poem with now numbers in it.

Comment: An experienced programmer never assumes that just because something isn't found in his test cases doesn't mean that it will never be found in production data :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks Phillip. Ill take your word on that (^). I just think it might throw off my teacher. I would vote you up but I can't :(

Comment: but you should be able to mark my answer as accepted, which would be even 50% better for my reputation score.

Comment: There we go. Accepted, it is.

Comment: Test driven development disagrees. If it's not spec'ed, your program simply can't work, you can't expect it to behave in some way if it wasn't designed to process that input.
Anyway, @op, I'd search for a non blank character after printing a newline.

Comment: After thinking about, numbers are accounted for, they just won't be output because they're not an alphabetic character, which is what I want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean Spidey.

Comment: Test Driven Development is a software development methodology where you first create automatic test cases which cover any possible use case and then write your program until they are all processed successful.

Comment: Ok, I ran into a problem. I'm getting a gap in the output after the title (There is four lines between the title and poem). Any tips? Here's the poem I have to output:         The Parsnip
 
 
 
 The parsnip, children, I repeat,
 Is simply an anemic beet,
 Some people call the parsnip edible;
 Myself,  I find this claim incredible.

Comment: Also, I'm using Xcode and can't enter the poem into the console because whenever I hit return to go the next line it runs the program. To get by this I'm just pasting the poem into the console. Will it run just as fine if I paste the poem into the console? Or is there another way to get around that? Thanks for the help.